# Razor syntax to show a drop down list in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have in my view model, a comma separated string:

```
vm.colours = "black, white, blue, green"
```

In my Razor page, I want to show a drop down list, so I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.colours, new SelectList(Model.colours))
```

However, this gives me a select list item for every LETTER in the string.

Is there any way I can amend this, to give me a select list item for each colour?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you just send a string, which is just an array of characters, so in this context it's interpreted as such. Use `Split` method to separate the elements you want.

Edit:

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16010321/1816426) for code example of using `Split` in this case.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer if this code won't even compile? This is misleading for other people searching for the right answer

Comment: @vonv. you're right, I just updated the line in one place and didn't check it. I removed the code to not mislead, I'll check it later. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: No worries @KonradGadzina, we all want SO to be a good resource for devs so in the end the objective is to have the best content there is. Thanks for editing your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

> @Html.DropDownList(m => m.colours, new SelectList(Model.colours))

No overload of `DropDownList` accepts an expression. For that code to work you need to do it like this:

```
Html.DropDownList("give_it_a_name", new SelectList(Model.colours))
```

Or perhaps you mean to use `DropDownListFor`, if yes then you need two things:

1. A property that will accept the item that is selected from the dropdown
2. Your list that will be used to show options in the dropdown

Your view should look like this:

```
public class YourVM 
{
    public string SelectedColor{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Colors {get;set;}
}
```

You need to have something like this in your controller:

```
var colors = "black, white, blue, green";
vm.colours = colors.Split(',');
```

And finally in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.colours, new SelectList(Model.Colors))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like colours is not an `IEnumerable<string>` but just a `string`. As the `SelectList` will enumerate over the object passed into, that means in this case an enumeration over a string which returns all characters. Please try it using a string array:

`vm.colours = new string[] { "black", "white", "blue", "green" };`

The call to `Html.DropDownList` remains the same.